# Generic type constraint of new() and an abstract base class

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class, base-class

Here we have a simple class herarchy, and use of generics with a [type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) of `new()`

```
public abstract class Base 
{
}

public class Derived : Base
{
}

public class TestClass
{
    private void DoSomething<T>(T arg) where T : new()
    {
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Derived d1 = new Derived();
        DoSomething(d1); // compiles

        Base d2 = new Derived();
        DoSomething(d2); // compile error
    }
}
```

The code fails to compile at the indicated line, with an error of:

> 'Base' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Foo.DoSomething(T)'

This error is clear and makes sense, but I had hoped that the compiler would understand that all derivations of `Base` (that could be instantiated at this point) do have a public parameterless constructor.

Would this be theoretically possible for the compiler?

Comment: It's this line that worries me more `non-abstract type` than the parameter-less constructor clause

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alas you have to explicitly give the type

```
DoSomething<Derived>(d2);
```

theoretically is not possible to create something that is abstract

Comment: I like the "theoretically" part. Makes me feel like Jon Skeet will pop in, do some magic, and there you go, instantiated abstract object.

Comment: On which version of .NET does it compile if d2 is declared as abstract Base?

Answer (score 2):

[new Constraint (C# Reference):](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx)

> To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

Calling:

```
Base d2 = new Derived();
DoSomething(d2);
```

You are in fact doing:

```
Base d2 = new Derived();
DoSomething<Base>(d2);
```

Since the `Base` is abstract, compilation error occurs.

So, you have to cast explicitly:

```
Base d2 = new Derived();
DoSomething((Derived) d2);
```

How could you ensure the compiler, that anyone ever put there something, that is not abstract?

The only manner that I see would be, if we got a keyword like "must-inherit-to-non-astract" and then create `public must-inherit-to-non-abstract abstract class Base`. After that, the compiler could be sure, that if you put the base instance into your method, that will be in fact a subclass, that is non-abstract and therefore can be instantiated.